# Is there a standard symbol for the relational operator "is a permutation of"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Is there a standard symbol that would mean something like "is a permutation /anagram/reordering/of"?

Maybe it is one of the [Unicode "equals" symbols](https://www.alt-codes.net/equal-symbols) that include a diacritic mark?

For example with the hypothetical symbol "" we would have:

(1, 1, 2, 5)   (5, 1, 2, 1)

Comment: I don't know of any dedicated symbols. You could define an equivalence relation $\sim$ by $p\sim q\iff p=\sigma(q)$ for some permutation $\sigma$.

Comment: This is related to permutations, but I don’t think there is an acknowledged single symbol.

Comment: Maybe a nonce symbol with the sigma over equals like $σ \above 0pt ＝$

Comment: there is no such symbol